# react-testing-library queryByTestId returning NULL

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm making the switch from using `enzyme` to `react-testing-library` for testing my components.

I have a simple component `CustomModal` which acts much like a wrapper around the `Modal` from `reactstrap`. **I am trying to test that my `CustomModal` includes the child elements that it ought to.**

Taking my cues from [this article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/making-your-ui-tests-resilient-to-change) and [this article](https://blog.bitsrc.io/testing-react-applications-with-react-testing-library-da66aaef740a), I am adding `data-testid` attributes to my children, and then I am using `getByTestId` and `queryByTestId`. But, for some reason, my queries are not finding the child nodes that, as far as I can tell, are there.

**Is there something I am doing wrong in my test setup, or am I misunderstanding how `react-testing-library` should be used?**

The basic code, along with the test (which is failing), can be found in this CodeSandbox:
[image: Edit react-testing-library queryByTestId]

My basic `CustomModal` component looks like this:

```
/*
 * src/components/CustomModal/index.js
 */

import React from "react";
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from "reactstrap";

const getSanitizedModalProps = props => {
  let modalProps = { ...props };
  delete modalProps.onConfirm;
  delete modalProps.onCancel;
  delete modalProps.headerText;
  delete modalProps.children;
  modalProps.isOpen = modalProps.isOpen === true;
  return modalProps;
};

export default props => {
  return (
    <Modal data-testid="modal" {...getSanitizedModalProps(props)}>
      <ModalHeader data-testid="modal-header">{props.headerText}</ModalHeader>
      <ModalBody data-testid="modal-body">{props.children}</ModalBody>
      <ModalFooter data-testid="modal-footer">
        <Button data-testid="confirm-button" onClick={props.onConfirm}>
          Confirm
        </Button>
        <Button data-testid="cancel-button" onClick={props.onCancel}>
          Cancel
        </Button>
      </ModalFooter>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

My test file looks like this:

```
/*
 * src/components/CustomModal/CustomModal.test.js
 */

import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-testing-library";
import CustomModal from "./index";

const TEST_IDS = {
  modal: "modal",
  header: "modal-header",
  body: "modal-body",
  footer: "modal-footer",
  cancel: "cancel-button",
  confirm: "confirm-button"
};

describe("<Modal />", () => {
  const headerText = "hello world";
  it("renders all of the children", () => {
    const { queryByTestId } = render(<CustomModal headerText={headerText} />);

    // The following assertions all fail
    expect(queryByTestId(TEST_IDS.modal)).toBeTruthy(); 
    expect(queryByTestId(TEST_IDS.header)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(queryByTestId(TEST_IDS.body)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(queryByTestId(TEST_IDS.footer)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(queryByTestId(TEST_IDS.cancel)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(queryByTestId(TEST_IDS.confirm)).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modal is closed, you need to pass `isOpen` to it:

```
render(<CustomModal headerText={headerText} isOpen />);
```